# unable to run reports in SpagoBI

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, birt

I installed SpagoBI server 3.6 but could not able to run any reports created by me except the example reports given by default. When i execute my jasper report it shows "error check in log files".

This is the log file error:

```
ERROR it.eng.spagobi.utilities.engines.AbstractEngineStartServlet.handleException:64 - Service execution failed
it.eng.spagobi.utilities.engines.SpagoBIEngineException: An error occurred while executing report. Check log file for more information
    at it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.services.JasperReportEngineStartAction.doService(JasperReportEngineStartAction.java:105)
    at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.engines.AbstractEngineStartServlet.doService(AbstractEngineStartServlet.java:47)
    at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.service.AbstractBaseServlet.service(AbstractBaseServlet.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.SpagoBIAccessFilter.doFilter(SpagoBIAccessFilter.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.JasperReportEngineRuntimeException: Impossible to run report
    at it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.JasperReportEngineInstance.runReport(JasperReportEngineInstance.java:118)
    at it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.services.JasperReportEngineStartAction.doService(JasperReportEngineStartAction.java:95)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.JasperReportEngineRuntimeException: Impossible to run report
    at it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.JasperReportEngineInstance.runReport(JasperReportEngineInstance.java:251)
    at it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.JasperReportEngineInstance.runReport(JasperReportEngineInstance.java:116)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: it.eng.spagobi.utilities.engines.SpagoBIEngineRuntimeException: Impossible to deserialize catalogue
    at it.eng.qbe.dataset.QbeDataSet.getCatalogue(QbeDataSet.java:252)
    at it.eng.qbe.dataset.QbeDataSet.init(QbeDataSet.java:82)
    at it.eng.qbe.dataset.QbeDataSet.loadData(QbeDataSet.java:104)
    at it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.JasperReportEngineInstance.runReport(JasperReportEngineInstance.java:205)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at it.eng.qbe.dataset.QbeDataSet.getCatalogue(QbeDataSet.java:242)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    ... 24 more
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The innermost exception means that the class org.json.JSONObject was not found (Most likely found here: http://www.json.org/), this usually is because the corresponding jar for such class is not found in the classpath, so you need to download the jar for this class and put it in the classpath of Spago, i'm not familiar with Spago but you should find how to put this jar in the classpath on their documentation.